# this .htaccess not working. Cannot see why

Tags: .htaccess

Dear all I have got the following code in my .htaccess in the folder localhost/demo/

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and the following line is active on httpd.config

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

still if I type localhost/demo/model I can still see and browse the sub directory. All I want is to redirect all URL to index.php. Can you help?

Comment: check the permissions on the `.htaccess` file

Comment: You've restarted apache after enabling mod-rewrite?

Comment: full permission to everyone? Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

...means do not rewrite if the URL points to an existing directory. Remove it, and the rewrite should take effect and not let you browse the subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you. Only one question (if you don't mind). if I type  localhost/demo/model it goes indeed to  localhost/demo/index.php but all CSS styles are lost! Any idea?

Comment: @user1536396 Hm, does the css work for other rewritten URLs on localhost/demo? Where are the CSS files placed?

Comment: CSS files are in localhost/demo/VIEW/LIB/CSS

Comment: @user1536396 It's most likely mod_dir that interacts badly with mod_rewrite, when I disable it, the redirect works. You can either add `DirectorySlash off` to your htaccess or you can disable mod_dir in httpd.conf